# How to use Spring MVC DataBinding to instantiate a SubClass

Tags: data-binding, spring-mvc

Consider the following three classes, C is a subclass of B. B is a field of A.
How to pass An instance of class A which contains an instance of class C as its field, from JSP pages to Spring Controller method?

```
class A{
     private B b;
     public B getB(){return b;}
     public void setB( B b){ this.b = b;}
}

class B{
     private int id;     
     public int getId(){return id;}
     public void setId(int id){this.id = id;}
}
class C extends B{
     private name;
     public String getName(){return name;}
     public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
}
```

The sample Spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class Handler{
     @RequestMapping("/work")
     public String work(@RequestParam( "objA" ) A objA ){
         if( C.getClass().isInstance( objA.getB() ) ){
               System.out.println("It works.");
          }
     }
}
```

The supposed JSP page but doesn't work:

```
<form method="post" action="work" commandName="objA" >

        <input type="submit" value="submit" /><br/>

        <input type="hidden" name="b.name" value="name" /><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="b.id" value="1" /><br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use Jackson to bind data. Then we can treat it as [Jackson Polymorphic Type Handling Problem](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/03/entry_372.html)
Here is a [link](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) about how to use Jackson and ajax in Spring mvc context.